# SSH- or sudo-like behaviour with python click

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I use `click` for my Python script command line handling. I'd like to achieve behaviour similar to SSH or Sudo, i.e. parse some known arguments and take everything else as is without any processing.

For example, consider this command line:

```
ssh -v myhost echo -n -e foo bar
```

Notice that `-v` will be processed by SSH, but `echo` and everything after it will not be processed as options.

Here is my current implementation:

```
@click.command()
@click.option('-v', '--verbose', is_flag=True)
@click.argument('target')
@click.argument('command', nargs=-1)
def my_command(verbose, target, command):
    print('verbose:', verbose)
    print('target:', target)
    print('command:', command)
```

It does not work as expected:

```
$ python test.py -v hostname echo -e foo
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] TARGET [COMMAND]...
Try "test.py --help" for help.

Error: no such option: -e
```

I can add `--` delimiter to force the expected behavior:

```
$ python /tmp/test.py -v hostname -- echo -e foo
verbose: True
target: hostname
command: ('echo', '-e', 'foo')
```

But it is not what I want.

I can also add `ignore_unknown_options=True`:

```
@click.command(context_settings=dict(ignore_unknown_options=True))
...
```

```
$ python /tmp/test.py -v hostname echo -e foo
verbose: True
target: hostname
command: ('echo', '-e', 'foo')
```

But it won't work with *known* options, like `-v` in this case.

So the question is: how to instruct `click` to stop handling any options after certain `argument` is encountered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom `click.Command` class to automatically insert the `--` where needed like:

#### Custom Class:

```
class RealNargsMinusOne(click.Command):

    def parse_args(self, ctx, args):
        orig_args = list(args)
        try:
            return super(RealNargsMinusOne, self).parse_args(ctx, args)
        except click.NoSuchOption as exc:
            first_unknown = str(exc).split()[-1]
            position_unknown = orig_args.index(first_unknown)
            orig_args.insert(position_unknown, '--')
            return super(RealNargsMinusOne, self).parse_args(ctx, orig_args)
```

#### Using the Custom Class:

To use the custom class, pass it as the `cls` argument to the command decorator like:

```
@click.command(cls=RealNargsMinusOne)
....
def my_command():
    ....
```

#### How does this work?

This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The `@click.command()` decorator usually instantiates a `click.Command` object but allows this behavior to be over ridden with the `cls` parameter. So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Command` in our own class and over ride desired methods.

In this case we over ride `click.Command.parse_args()` and catch the `click.NoSuchOption` exception.  We then amend the argument list with a `--` in front of the offending option and retry the parse.

#### Test Code:

```
import click

@click.command(cls=RealNargsMinusOne)
@click.option('-v', '--verbose', is_flag=True)
@click.argument('target')
@click.argument('command', nargs=-1)
def my_command(verbose, target, command):
    print('verbose:', verbose)
    print('target:', target)
    print('command:', command)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        '-v hostname echo -e foo',
        '-v hostname -x echo -e foo',
        '-x hostname -x echo -e foo',
        '--help',
        '',
    )

    import sys, time

    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            my_command(cmd.split(), allow_extra_args=True)

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> -v hostname echo -e foo
verbose: True
target: hostname
command: ('echo', '-e', 'foo')
-----------
> -v hostname -x echo -e foo
verbose: True
target: hostname
command: ('-x', 'echo', '-e', 'foo')
-----------
> -x hostname -x echo -e foo
verbose: False
target: -x
command: ('hostname', '-x', 'echo', '-e', 'foo')
-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] TARGET [COMMAND]...

Options:
  -v, --verbose
  --help         Show this message and exit.
-----------
> 
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] TARGET [COMMAND]...

Error: Missing argument "target".
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this approach but didn't hit upon editing arguments list in runtime. Good catch!